# Preselect checkboxes before form submit or first time load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

In a particular form I have a div with 5 checkboxes and I like to preselected all 5 on first load (or when the form has not been submitted).

I thought this was ok, but when I uncheck 2 boxes and I submit the form which reload the same page, all 5 boxes are checked again. And not just the selected ones. 
I am using a simple PHP ternary to check which div-view box is selected and this works if I remove the following .js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //Preselect All Div Views
     $("#div-views input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);

    ...
    });
```

I need to trigger the .js just once, I guess. I am using jquery for most of the javascript handling.

Comment: `when I uncheck 2 boxes and I submit the form which reload the same page, all 5 boxes are checked again` this is because HTML is stateless. This means that the previous page state has absolutely no bearing on the next page, or the same page when reloaded. If you need that behaviour you will need to store the state of the page before reloading and recallthe state when the new page loads. To do that you can use local/session storage, the querystring, cookies, or a server side data store.

Comment: could i also use just a variable which is set to true/false

Comment: Sure, but as I mentioned above, you need to store that value somewhere which lasts longer than a single page lifecycle.

Comment: I am happy with just a simple variable in the browser url at the moment

Comment: It sounds like submitting the form via AJAX would solve your problem, wouldn't it? Or if you really need to store the value somewhere (and don't wanna use backend databases), you could use localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your javascript code if your form hasn't been submitted yet.

## Php

```
<?php
// If the button is in the $_POST var (or $_GET), the form has already been sent.
if (!isset($_POST['MyButtonName'])) {
?>     
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //Preselect All Div Views
    $("#div-views input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
<?php } ?>
```